# Как посчитать количество цифр в содержимом текстового файла?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    string s = ""; //объявляем строковую переменную, в которую будет считываться весь текст из файла 
    string[] textMass; //объявляем массив строк textMass, который будет считывать каждую цифру из строки s
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("1234.txt"); //чтение файлов 
    if (sr.EndOfStream != true) //цикл
    {
        s = sr.ReadToEnd();            
    }
    textMass = s.Split(' ');         
    Console.WriteLine("Количество цифр:");
    Console.WriteLine(textMass.LongLength);
    sr.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();         
}
```

Нужно считать содержимое текстового файла и подсчитать число цифр в нем. Как это сделать?

Comment: 1. Считать весь файл в string 2. регуляркой получить все числа и подсчитать их

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать регулярные выражения:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    string s = "";//объявляем строковую переменную, в которую будет считываться весь текст из файла 
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("1234.txt");//чтение файлов     
    if (sr.EndOfStream != true)// цикл
    {
        s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }   
    // "\D" - символы не цифры заменяем на ""
    string digits = Regex.Replace(s, @"\D", "");
    Console.WriteLine("Количество цифр:");
    Console.WriteLine(digits.Length);
    sr.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();            
}
```

Или воспользоваться методом `IsDigit`:

```
char[] digits = s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(digits.Length);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634761/7099599

Answer (score 2):

- Считываем содержимое файла в строку с помощью метода `File.ReadAllText`
- Выбираем из строки только цифры с помощью `Where(char.IsDigit)`
- Считаем количество цифр с помощью `Count()`

Итоговый код:

```
int count = File.ReadAllText("1234.txt").Where(char.IsDigit).Count();
```